# ¿Porqué no usar llamadas sincronas?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async

Estoy desarrollando una app con Vue.js y estoy usando Axios. Estoy en un punto en el cual la asincronia de Axios me esta dando problemas. He leído en varios lugares (por ejemplo [esta pregunta del sitio en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46347778/how-to-make-axios-synchronous)) que no "deberia" usar llamadas sincronas y developer.mozilla.org [explica](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) que la razón para no hacerlo es por cuestiones de rendimiento.

Entiendo a la perfección el tema de rendimiento, ya que cada llamada tendría que esperar a que la anterior termine para poder continuar, lo cual, en ciertos escenarios, seria regresar 30 años de avances de rendimiento.

Mi pregunta es, ¿existe alguna otra razón especifica y cuantificable por la cual no deba usar llamadas sincronas o es solo por el rendimiento?

<sub>P.D. Tengo una solida base de conocimiento acerca de promesas u otras funciones de Javascript, y pienso que el problema que tengo en este momento es algorítmico, pero creo que un cambio en la programación podría resolverlo, de allí la pregunta.</sub>

<sub>P.D. 2 Entiendo que muchos pensaran que la pregunta es muy amplia, pero no lo es. Solo quiero entender razones especificas para no utilizar una funcionalidad de un lenguaje de programación..</sub>

Comment: No es solo rendimiento, es un mejor manejo de tu información en un escenario real las respuestas demoran en ser procesadas, es ahí donde ingresa la asincronía la cual hará que esperes a que el procesamiento termine para que puedas continuar.

Comment: Adicional la interfaz corre sobre el hilo principal de tu aplicación, si utilizamos unicamente llamadas sincronas estas se ejecutan en el hilo principal lo que bloquearía tu interface hasta que se obtenga una respuesta de la promesa, esto para el usuario es "bloquear" la interfaz dando una percepción de que la aplicación "se congeló" o simplemente "dejo de funcionar" entonces si tu funcion tarda 30s en ejecutarse el usuario se queda 30s sin poder utilizar su interfaz.

Answer (score 4):

Las llamadas síncronas no aportan nada.

No tienen *pros* pero sí tienen *contras*: bloquean el hilo principal, con lo que las acciones del usuario se ignoran, las animaciones y transiciones CSS se congelan, no se pueden hacer dos llamadas paralelas... etc.

> Solo quiero entender razones especificas para no utilizar una
>   funcionalidad de un lenguaje de programación.

Hay funcionalidades que se consideran dañinas con el paso del tiempo: Javascript tiene la palabra reservada `with` que nadie **debería** usar porque se considera dañina, como **goto** en otros lenguajes.

```js
let obj = {
  hola: 'esto es un texto',
  b: 42
 };
 
function test1(a) {
  with (a) {
    console.log(hola);
    console.log(b);
  }
}
test1(obj);
```

Tanto, que en modo estricto (`'use strict;'`) da un error de compilación:

```js
let obj = {
  hola: 'esto es un texto',
  b: 42
 };
 
function test1(a) {
  'use strict';
  with (a) {
    console.log(hola);
    console.log(b);
  }
}
test1(obj);
```

Del mismo modo, intentar usar una llama AJAX síncrona lanza un aviso en la consola, diciendo que no lo hagas:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help,
>   check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Answer (score 2):

¿Porqué no usar llamadas síncronas?

- EL proyecto cargará de forma síncrona. Secuencialmente mientras más elementos mas se notara la pérdida de rendimiento en comparación a peticiones síncronas.
- Bloqueo del hilo principal, si en tu aplicación se encuentran peticiones de por medio se bloqueara completamente mientras la petición se realice.

Una app,página asíncrona no deberia dar ningun tipo de problemas te recomendaria verificar la forma en la que está implementando tus promesas o verificar bin por que estas teniendo problema. 'Espero haberte ayudado'.